# Постоянный мониторинг папки реализованный на c#

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Пытаюсь написать крошечную программу на c#, которая будет мониторить активность заданной папки и выводить информацию о времени последнего изменения в Label. Пытался реализовать этот процесс через While:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool start = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button1.Text = ("Начать проверку");
        button2.Text = ("Остановить проверку");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        while (start == false)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users");
            label1.Text = ("Полный путь: " + dir.FullName);
            label2.Text = ("Последнее обновление: " + dir.LastWriteTime);
        }

    }
}
```

Но, данный пример кода не делает вообще ничего.

Comment: Ну понятно, start везде равен true, а вы проверяете что он false

Comment: `while (true)` — это тру! `while (false)` — это дважды тру!

Comment: Я бы очень советовал использовать специально обученный класс [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо бесконечного цикла.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Ссылка:

Вот ссылка на [знакомство с наблюдением за событиями файловой системы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch2s8yd7(v=vs.90).aspx)!

Там как раз написано про наблюдение за событиями файловой системы и примеры есть.

**[FileSystemWatcher.Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.90).aspx)** - событие происходит при изменении файла или каталога в заданном пути [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path(v=vs.90).aspx).

**[FileSystemWatcher.Renamed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed(v=vs.90).aspx)** - событие происходит при переименовании файла или каталога в заданном пути [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path(v=vs.90).aspx).

> Событие Changed возникает неожиданно при переименовании файла, но оно не возникает при изменении имени каталога.

Для отслеживания переименований используйте событие Renamed.

## Пример:

```
public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).