# Как узнать, что в проекте(файлах и папках) были изменения?

Tags: c#, c++, golang

Нужно, что б как только в определённой папке что-то изменилось-сразу-же выполнить код.
То-есть я в проекте меняю файлы,добавляю,удаляю папки и сразу-же нужно изменить файл updated.txt, записав в него время обновления.

Comment: операционная система?

Comment: Ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428820/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c

Comment: @strangeqargo windows

Comment: низкоуровневое: под линуксом inotify, есть порт  для винды win-inotify,  если вам для разработки - нормальные IDE сами видят обновления. Фрейморвки: для симфони есть например, assetic. Inotify оч удобная штука.

Comment: IDE и гит у меня видит, но мне нужно дополнительную программку для отслежки файловой системы, а код  @NMD я не оч понял,как собрать в кучу

Comment: можно [`watchmedo` утилитой воспользоваться (кросс-платформенная, реализована на Питоне)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) (позволяет запустить команду, если указанные события ("в определённой папке что-то изменилось") произошли).

Comment: через события системного аудита не пробовали?

Comment: @rdorn я нашёл на C# вариант, но "чёто" все минус ставят,непонятно за что-там конкретный ответ. Но про системный аудит почитаю

Comment: @RakzinRoman просто это стандартная фича Win. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538395/198316 тут можно посмотреть как его включить, в том вопросе был аудит попыток входа в систему, но там же включается аудит файловой системы, а настроить потом можно для каждой папки индивидуально. Посмотрите, если вам подойдет, то напишу подробно про аудит для файлов.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Готовая программка на C#, отслеживающая изменения
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

Comment: Это вы так попиарили свой проект?

Comment: @"Nick Volynkin" - я не понимаю- зачем минусовать ответ, если он по теме. Исходник вообще не мой на самом то деле и никто ничего не пиарит. Подсказали здесь https://toster.ru/q/341170?e=4178854#answer_item_858564.

Comment: минусы не мои, я просто разместил комментарий)

Comment: Думаю, минусы по двум причинам: это только ссылка, чего для ответа недостаточно и 2) слегка похоже на саморекламу. Предлагаю либо расширить ответ, либо ссылку в комментарии оставить.

Comment: https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify  https://github.com/jpillora/spy

Answer (score 1):

В цикле проверять размер файлов (FileInfo.Length) в нужном каталоге, при изменении - анализировать изменившийся файл и писать изменения в updated.txt. В первый раз сделать слепок того, что есть. Далее ловить новые файлы или изменения.